# Proper notation of a relation

Tags: notation

Asking fellow mathematicians and typographers; what was it the proper, typographical, notation for a relation? E.g. consider “A to B is like 2 to 3”. This is written as “A:B=2:3”, but my question is about the spacing around “:”. Is it
$$\verb|A:B=2:3|\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad A:B=2:3$$
or
$$\verb|\text{$A$:$B$}=\text{2:3}|\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \text{$A$:$B$}=\text{2:3}$$
or, something in between,
$$\verb|A\!:\!B=2\!:\!3|\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad A\!:\!B=2\!:\!3$$
Perhaps the question is more for the LaTeX people, but I thought of asking the mathematicians first that have more general experience of mathematical notation. TIA.

Comment: All these notations are the same.

Comment: Not typographically. That was the ‘core’ of my question. How much space (if any) should be around “:”?

Comment: @mf67 I don't think there is such a standard in practice. By the way, what do you mean by a relation, precisely?

Comment: Like when it says ”The sides of a triangle are in the relation ‘3:4:5’...”

Comment: I wouldn’t write it with an equals sign in the first place: the usual expression, in my experience, is $$A:B\ ::\ C:D$$ and is read ‘$A$ is to $B$ as $2$ is to $3$’.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that. Thanks!